# replace duplicates in column values with column value plus increasing numbers. Using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this. Output be like whenever there will be any duplicate value in the column on specific "id" then those column values will be appended by increasing numeric value like this. A, A_1, A_2 and so on.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],'Col':['A','B','A','A','D','A','A','A']})
```

[image]

output will be like :

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Using `np.where` concept here.

```
s = df.groupby(['id','Col']).cumcount()
df['Col'] = np.where(s!=0, df['Col'] + '_' + s.astype(str), df['Col'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter, add `_` from right side by [`Series.radd`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.radd.html), remove first values and add to `Col` column:

```
df['Col'] += df.groupby(['id','Col']).cumcount().astype(str).radd('_').replace('_0','')
print (df)
   id  Col
0   1    A
1   1    B
2   1  A_1
3   2    A
4   2    D
5   2  A_1
6   2  A_2
7   2  A_3
```